# Simple module for creating histogram

Tags: python, histogram

As a newbie programmer trying to create a simple module for printing histogram.(### used for printing histogram as i am not familiar with using utf-8 code
here is the program

this porgam as an example list taken 36 hashes but does not create the 4 pillar histogram

This program idea is program reads the list-x element by element and if element is equal to list max value it prints a hash, reduces max value by 1 and also all elements equal to max value. if list element is less than max value blank is printed. as iteration proceeds at some time more and more elements will print hash to create histogram and process terminates when all list elements are zero and at this point list element labels are printed.
How to modify the program to print 4 pillar histogram or n pillar histogram where n is list length

```
def histogram(x):


    while x!=[0]*len(x):
       for i in range(len(x)):
           y=max(x)

           if x[i]==y:
               print("###"),
               y-=1
               x[i]-=1


           if x[i]<y:
               print("   "),

           if x==[0]*len(x):
               print "  A  ","  B  " ,"  C ","  D "




x=[10,2,12,22]
print histogram(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish. But I'm assuming you're trying to make some ascii-representation of a histrogram.

You can convert your input (a list of integers) to a list of strings with lengths matching that of each value in the list with a list-comprehension:

```
hist = (x*'#' for x in input)
```

The longest string will be given by

```
m = max(input)
```

Which you can use to pad the strings:

```
histPadded = (x.rjust(m, " ") for x in hist)
```

And then transpose it:

```
flipped = flipped = zip(*list(histPadded))
```

And then you can print it out:

```
list(map(lambda x: print("".join(map(str, x))), flipped))
```

The outer `list` is needed to force evaluation.

Comment: Thanks. But would appreciate response why my version doesn't print in 4 neat pillars as per eg list taken. How to make the program iterate over the list & print every iteration in new line to get the histo

Comment: There could be many reasons. I think you should reconsider the overall structure of your solution. Try to split the problem up into smaller problems. Anyways. I've submitted a solution similiar to yours perhaps you can see for yourself what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On request here is an answer that looks like the original solution - just modified to give correct results.

```
def histogram(x):
    y=max(x)
    while x!=[0]*len(x):
        for i in range(len(x)):
            if x[i]==y:
                print("###"),
                x[i]-=1
            elif x[i]<y:
                print("   "),
        print("")
        y-=1
    print " A   B   C   D "
```

Answer (score 0):

This follows your idea of reducing the maximum value for each iteration.

```
def h(x):
    mx =max(x)
    lx = len(x)
    m = []
    for v in x :
        # reduces max value by 1 in each ieration
        #                    VVVVVV
        m.append(["   "if v < mx-n else "***" for n in range(l)])
        #                    ^^^^^^
    return "\n".join(["  ".join(t) for t in zip(*m)]+
                     ["  ".join([" A "," B "," C "," D "," E ", " F "][:lx])])
```

testing

```
x=[10,2,12,11]
print h(x)
```

outputs

```
          ***     
          ***  ***
***       ***  ***
***       ***  ***
***       ***  ***
***       ***  ***
***       ***  ***
***       ***  ***
***       ***  ***
***       ***  ***
***  ***  ***  ***
***  ***  ***  ***
 A    B    C    D
```